# Rendering div that match array parameters

Tags: html, arrays, angular

I have an issue rendering parameters in Angular 8, I get datas from API that I need to render in divs that matchs those datas but I'm having an issue where the datas shows in **every** divs, here's what it looks like :

[image]

Here, "Drops","Misc","Network" are the main divs that need to render the lower-categories.
Altought, what I want is for example, to have only "Drops Aluminium" inside the **main** "Drops", only "VANNE" inside "Misc" and "Main" in "Network". The lower categories should only renders when they have their ids inside the **main** id ( see picture 2 below ).

What I have tried :

Binding the values inside the divs, since all main and lower categories have ids like so :

[image]

Here is a stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-me2ppb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thank you in advance for your time and help, it's much appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, could you just solve it with a nested loop in the template?

```
<div *ngFor="let main of total_by_level | keyvalue">
    {{label_name[main.key]}}
    <div *ngFor="let sub of main.value | keyvalue">
        {{label_name[sub.key]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

This would result in:

```
Network
Main
Drops
Drops Aluminium
Misc
VANNE
```

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here:

1. Adapt your HTML to loop around `total_by_level` and query `label_name` appropriately
2. Build the output in code

It looks like you have attempted both, and so are open to either. Personally, I prefer to do as much as possible in the code and keep the HTML as dumb as possible, so I would take approach 2.

In `ngOnInit()` (which should be where you do any initial processing), I would build an array based on the structure on `total_by_level`.

```js
output: any[];

ngOnInit() {    
  this.output = Object.keys(this.total_by_level).map(levelKey => {
    const child = this.total_by_level[levelKey];

    return {
      level: {
        label: this.label_name[levelKey]          
      },
      children: Object.keys(child).map(childKey => ({
        label: this.label_name[childKey],
        value: child[childKey]
      }))
    };
  });
}
```

It then becomes simple to bind to this array in your HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of output">
  {{item.level.label}}
  <div *ngFor="let child of item.children">
    {{child.label}}
    {{child.value}}
  </div>
</div>
```

You are dealing with some odd data structures, and I'm not sure of your terminology, so I have guessed a little bit here. You can take the concept of this idea and work with it. I am also assuming that there is only ever 1 nested child in `total_by_level`.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upqdex

Comment: That's a really cool approach, I'll try both and see what feets me better but kinda like to keep the html as dumb as possible too :) Thank you!